# Unable to add PHP code snippet to Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, web, namespaces

We are currently testing out some PHP functions in Wordpress and it seems that in every example we try, an error is shown in the first line of code stating that 'MyNamespaceName' is unexpected.

The example:

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespaceName {
  
    // Regular PHP code
    function hello()
    {
        echo 'Hello I am Running from a namespace!';
    }
}
?>
```

The error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'MyNamespaceName' (T_STRING), expecting \ (T_NS_SEPARATOR) in /volume1/web/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/shortcode-handler.php(99) : eval()'d code on line 2

Comment: The syntax is valid -- I'll wager you're using an ancient PHP version that doesn't support namespaces.

Comment: Are you putting this code into the "Insert PHP Code Snippet" wordpress plugin?    I don't know it, but it looks like having namespaces and functions are beyond its capabilities.